# script to move folder based on modified date

Tags: bash, cron, pipe, mv, uuencode

first post. 
Background- My wife is a photographer, she take a lot of pictures and saves them to a drive (mnt/STStorage) while she is editing them, but never cleans up afterward. I have a drive that i would like to move the folders to based on modified date.(/mnt/LTStorage). 
Need help with a script that i can add to a cron job to run once a day 30 1 * * *
I would like for the script to..

1. Check /mnt/STStorage/ root folders for last modified date & if older
   than 14 days, move that folder and everything in it to
       /mnt/LTStorage/ while keeping the same folder name.
2. Then write what was moved to /mnt/STStorage/ so that we know what
   was moved and email me a log of folders moved.

OS CentOS 6.4

here is what i have, think this may work for now. Could be cleaner.

```
#/bin/bash
dt=$(date +%Y.%m.%d) 
From="/mnt/STStorage/"
To="/mnt/LTStorage/"

if [[ ! -d "$To" ]]; then
mkdir -p "$To"
fi

cd "$From"
for i in "$@"; do
find . -type d -mtime +14 -exec mv "{}" "$To" \; > "$From"/Moved."$dt".txt

uuencode "$From"/Moved."$dt".txt "$From"/Moved."$dt".txt | mail -s "Files Moved"
me@me.com
done
```

Then i will add this to crontab to run once a day.

Comment: You can add the verbose mode option to `mv`. Do this - `find . -type d -mtime +14 -exec mv -v "{}" "$To" \;`

Comment: how could i write the output of -v to a log and save to /mnt/STStorage and also email it? i tested -v and it prints out the file and where it was moved on the terminal

Comment: added that in the answer. I am not suggesting this is the best approach. But atleast you have something to play around with and customize it according to your needs like appending datestamp to log files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-exec` along with `find`. Something like:

```
find /mnt/STStorage/ -type d -mtime +14 -exec mv {} /mnt/LTStorage/ \;
```

- `-type d` will ensure only directories are moved.

Another option is to use `xargs`

```
 find /mnt/STStorage/ -type d -mtime +14 | xargs -I '{}' mv {} /mnt/LTStorage/
```

#### Update:

To add what is being moved, you can set the `verbose` mode option for `mv`

```
find /mnt/STStorage/ -type d -mtime +14 -exec mv -v {} /mnt/LTStorage/ \;
```

Since this will print everything on standard out. You can redirect it to a log file.

```
find /mnt/STStorage/ -type d -mtime +14 -exec mv {} /mnt/LTStorage/ \; > /mnt/STStorage/log.file
```

For emailing you can do something like -

```
uuencode /mnt/STStorage/log.file /mnt/STStorage/log.file | mail -s "this is my subject line" chip@email.com
```

Comment: Thank you, that got me started on the right path. have another questions after my updated code above.

Comment: Thank you, i have it working correctly so far, just have to add the email to it. Could i use something like && at the end of saving the log file?

Comment: After you have created the log file, add this command on the next line `uuencode "$From"/Moved."$dt".txt "$From"/Moved."$dt".txt | mail -s "Whatever Subject" chip@email.com`